# Looking for an excel formular which outputs the count of empty rows next to specific numbers?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is a snippet from my actual table (the real one is MUCH longer). What formular can I use to get the total count of empty rows next to the 10's ?

**more specific: in my example we can see 2 empty spaces (next to B10 and B24); I'd like the sum of all empty spaces next to the 10.**

[image]

Comment: "I'd like the sum of all empty spaces next to the 10" easy: the sum of empty spaces is `0`. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the Cells are populated(formula vs. truly empty)

You can try:

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,10,C:C,"")
```

But that requires that the blanks are empty strings and not truly blank.  For truly blank:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($B$1:$B$1000=10)*(LEN($C$1:$C$1000)=0))
```

Comment: Thanks, that works!

Comment: @tufofamun please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 0):

*There are several methods to attain the answer, here I would like to suggest few.*

[image]

**Method 1:**

- Formula ib cell `C122`:

  ```
  =INT(SUMPRODUCT((($B$97:$B$120=10))/COUNTIF($C$97:$C$120,$C$97:$C$120&"")))
  ```

**N.B.**

- To make the formula dynamic you can use cell reference in place of criteria value (`10`).

  ```
  =INT(SUMPRODUCT((($B$97:$B$120=$B$122))/COUNTIF($C$97:$C$120,$C$97:$C$120&"")))
  ```
- Where `B122` comprises the criteria `10`.

---

- *Optionally you may use this one also:*

  `=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$97:$B$120=10),--($C$97:$C$120=""))`

---

**Method 2:**

- Formula in cell `D97`:

  `=AND(B97=10,LEN(C97)=0)`
- Final formula in cell `D122`:

`=COUNTIF($D$97:$D$120,TRUE)`

- *This may also use to apply `condition formatting` on `column C`*

---

- Later on for neatness you may hide `Helper Column`.
- You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.